# Mostrar contenido de un diccionario en Python en el mismo orden de insercion

Tags: python

Estoy intentando crear un diccionario para almacenar cantidad de incidencias ocurridas en un cada mes del año.

Todo esta bien al declarar los meses y almacenar los datos en el diccionario. Pero al intentar mostrar los datos siempre los muestra de manera alfabetica lo cual no es lo que deseo pues se puerde el orden logico de los meses.

Alguien tiene alguna idea...

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un diccionario (`dict`), al igual que los conjuntos(`set`) por definición no tiene orden interno, se implementan mediante tablas hash lo cual permite su eficiencia, con respecto a objetos ordenados como son las listas, en operaciones como la búsqueda. Puedes usar [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) si quieres un objeto lo más parecido posible a un diccionario pero que mantiene el orden de entrada.

```
import collections

d = collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys('abcdefghijk')
for k in d.keys():
    print(k)
```

---

### Actualización

A partir de Python 3.7 la implementación de los diccionarios ha cambiado y tenemos asegurado que  mantienen el orden de inserción de los items:

```
d = dict.fromkeys('abcdefghijk')
for k in d.keys():
    print(k)
```

En Python 3.6.x este comportamiento también existe, aunque oficialmente solo es considerado un efecto colateral de la implementación.

Comment: Me resolvio la primera parte pero ahora me muestra algo asi como 

OrderedDict([('jan', None), ('march', None), ('feb', None), ('april', None)])

Omitiendo el valor de cada llave...

Comment: @elMor3no edita tu pregunta y añade el código que estas usando para crear y leer el diccionario (o al menos algo que podamos reproducir). De lo contrario va a ser difícil saber que está pasando por nuestra parte... `'jan'`, `'march'`, etc son las claves pero no tienen valores asociados  (`None`). Saludos.

Comment: Lo solucione usando valores numericos en vez de palabras... Gracias